# how to improve memory usage when using GenericItemSimilarity in mahout(taste)

Tags: mahout

As we known, in genericItemSimilarity similarity between item1 and item2 is precomputed.

when we use GenericItemBasedRecommender to get recommendation,`the recommender need datamodel and similarity in memory at the same time`.According to the genericItemSimilarity,it offers a construction like this

```
  public GenericItemSimilarity(ItemSimilarity otherSimilarity, DataModel dataModel) throws TasteException {
        long[] itemIDs = GenericUserSimilarity.longIteratorToList(dataModel.getItemIDs());
        initSimilarityMaps(new DataModelSimilaritiesIterator(otherSimilarity, itemIDs));
  }
```

just use dataModel to generate Similarity Maps in time .

Is it necessary to  store the similarity maps to Db/file ?

I find mahout 0.7 have a class named  `FileItemItemSimilarityIterator` can be helpful to read similarity maps from file.

is the `FileItemItemSimilarityIterator` or `AbstractJDBCInMemoryItemSimilarity(mahout 0.5)` redundancy or helpless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put the similarities in memory at all if they can be re-computed quickly on the fly.

If not, I suggest you simply prune similarities that have small absolute value. These affect the computation the least.

Comment: do some filter on the similarities maps to prune similarities may be help,thanks for you ans.